# distributed lock with zookeeper. how to avoid repeatly check the min node

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-lock

As we know that when implementing a distributed lock with Zookeeper and to avoid "herd effect", we will set watcher on the next lowest sequence number node. So, once the node is deleted , we can be notified immediately.

If the connection to lowest sequence number node is broken unexpectedly, we will check the nodes for a new "next lowest sequence number node" and set watcher on it.

But if the connection to this new founded node is broken now, we have to checkout the nodes for node we set watcher, again and again.

So, is there any solution to avoid this situation?